# Exclude UI elements from ReplayKit screen capturing

Tags: ios, screen, ios13, voice-recording, replaykit

While capturing the screen with Replaykit, how do i exclude ui elements from the recording?
I now in general i need to add them into a seprate window , but my previus attemnts where not successful. how do i create another window for the ui elements the posy ios 13 way ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        BottomUIWindow.windowScene = view.window?.windowScene
    }
```